# Grails not reading tomcat7 environment variable

Tags: tomcat, grails, tomcat7, environment-variables

We have set an evironment variable in the Tomcats context.xml file.

```
<Environment name="WEBAPP_CONFIG"
            value="/path/to/some/config/file"
            type="java.lang.String" override="false"/>
```

Inside Grails `Config.groovy` the variable is beeing read.

```
println "Use configuration file in environment: " + System.getenv("WEBAPP_CONFIG");
```

If we output the value of the variable the value is `null`

What could be the reason for the system variable not beeing recognized

Answer (score 0):

Those aren't environment variables to access via `System` but resources, that have to be read via the context.  Either access via context or add the var to the startup config of your tomcat.

Comment: By startup config you mean the setenv.sh file?

Comment: On Ubuntu 14.04 we created setenv.sh in /usr/share/tomcat7/bin. Neither appending -DWEBAPP_CONFIG=/path to CATALINA_OPTS neither exporting shell variable name in that file did not help. The same approach works on Debian, though. Does Tomcat 7 on Ubuntu have some specifics for configuration?